# Enabled profiler in admin and index.php but emtpy tables

Tags: magento-1.9, profiler

I did enabled the profiler at *System->Configuration->Developer->Debug->Profiler* and I commented out the line `Varien_Profiler::enable();` inside the `index.php` file.

But when I refresh the page, the table at the bottom is displayed empty.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the profiler output from `System->Configuration->Developer->Debug->Profiler`

Comment: I did enable Profiler function in  System->Configuration->Developer->Debug->Profiler

Comment: Check if it's disabled in store view scope.

Comment: Nope it is not, all are set to use default config. And I did changed it in default config. I only  see empty tables right now.

Comment: What magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: How is this the answer if you already did this? im confused

Answer (score 13):

Go to your /index.php and search for

```
Varien_Profiler::enable();
```

In your case the line should be commented. Uncomment it and you should see the profiler's contents.

Comment: This post should be answer to the question ...

Answer (score 6):

> **If you want to enable profiler, Here is the way**

1. `Admin Dashboard >> System >> Configuration >> Developer >> Debug >> Profiler`
2. Open “index.php” file located at the MAGENTO_ROOT folder in editor and find the link of code `#Varien_Profiler::enable();`. Uncomment this line and save like below

   ```
   require_once $mageFilename;

   Varien_Profiler::enable();

   if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
     Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
   }
   ```

Thats all, profiler has been enabled.

[image]

> **If you want to enable sql profiler, Here is the way**

To enable sql profiling,

1. you need to enable “Profiler” from admin
2. Open the `local.xml` config file located in `/app/etc/` folder and add the node `<profiler>true</profiler>`

Example :

```
<resources>
 <db>
  <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
 </db>
 <default_setup>
  <connection>
   <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
   <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
   <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
   <dbname><![CDATA[magento_1_8_1_0]]></dbname>
   <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
   <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
   <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
   <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
   <active>1</active>
   <profiler>true</profiler>
  </connection>
 </default_setup>
</resources>
```

save the file and clear the cache.

[image]

Comment: sadly i have done all this and i still get no profiler data showing up on the frontend :\

Comment: If i enable profile all the customers able to see the profiler right? how to enable profiler only for admin?@zed Blackbeard

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a multilanguage Magento istallation or if you installed it in a subfolder make sure you've also uncommented

```
Varien_Profiler::enable();
```

in the subfolder's index.php

otherwise you'll see an empty table when visiting that subfolder (i.e. www.mysite.com/en/)